# "It does not take me long to do it well"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Suppose I would like to say "It does not take me long to do it well". Which of the following are correct, and what differences in nuances might each of them have?

- "Ne necesas ke mi longe fari ĝin bone"
- "Ne necesas al mi longe fari ĝin bone"
- "Ne bezonas ke mi longe fari ĝin bone"
- "Ne bezonas al mi longe fari ĝin bone"
- (the above four again, but with "bone" right after "fari")
- (likewise, but with "bone" between "longe" and "fari")
- (likewise, but with "bone" before "longe")

What other ways are there to express this idea?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably say this like:

> Mi ne bezonas longan tempon por fari ĝin bone.

I think when the “to” before a verb in English can be replaced by “in order to”, it’s better to add the “por” in an Esperanto translation to make the meaning clear.

Some comments on your examples:

> Ne necesas ke mi longe fari ĝin bone

This one is not correct because it has a subject with an infinitive (*mi fari*). It sounds more like you are saying that it’s not necessary to do it at all.

> Ne necesas al mi longe fari ĝin bone

I think this one is a good translation but to my ear it would sound better if it was “por fari” because it’s not clear whether the *longe* is describing *fari* or whether it is the subject of *necesas*.

> Ne bezonas ke mi longe fari ĝin bone

This has the same problem as the first one.

> Ne bezonas al mi longe fari ĝin bone

I think *necesi* is the right word rather than *bezoni*. *Bezoni* is a transitive verb so if you want to use it you really need to make *mi* be the subject like in my proposal at the top.

Regarding the word order, I think putting *bone* at the end sounds the best, otherwise putting it before *fari* works too. The latter is the natural word order but putting it at the end changes the emphasis and I think it better matches the meaning of the English sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Ne daŭras longe al mi fari ĝin bone.

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus:

"ĝi ne necesas longe ke mi faru ĝin bone"

I believe you would require the subjunctive ("faru") in this sentence.

Comment: "It" in the beginning of the English phrase is probably a formal subject, only required by the strict word order requirement in English. So it doesn't translate to _ĝi_.

Answer (score 0):

Mia propono: Ne necesas longe al mi fari ĝin bone.

Simila ekzemplo el Tekstaro:

> Ne necesos longe al mi tualeti.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `bezoni = to need` that is correct here, and not `necesi = to be necessary`.

```
Mi ne bezonas longan tempon por ke mi faru ĝin bone.
Mi ne bezonas longe por fari ĝin bone.
```

The normal word order would be:

```
Mi ne bezonas longe por bone fari ĝin.
```

But to stress that to do it *well* instead of floppy, *bone* can be put not in the normal order.

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus:

```
Mi ne bezonas longan tempon tion bone fari.
```